# Unknown Java maven compilation error: R1549aadb

Tags: java, maven, junit5, java-module, maven-compiler-plugin

Whilst modularizing and migrating a Java 8 project to Java 17 an unknown maven error has been encountered.

The project has non-modular dependencies.

The regular classes and test classes (JUnit5) compile and run fine through Eclipse (without invoking maven).

The regular classes compile fine with maven, however when maven compiles the test classes (JUnit5) errors such as are reported:

```
[ERROR] /C:/some/path/to/a/source/file.java:[11,15] cannot access org
  R1549aadb
```

Where `org` is assumed to be the first portion of a package name, other examples encountered include `java`, `javax`.

The line number always seems to correspond to an import statement. in this case line [11] was: `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;`

**Anyone familiar with this kind of error?**

**Does anyone know what `R1549aadb` refers to?**

Comment: You have garbled the compilation error message, but it looks like it might be an obfuscated package name.  Look at the source code you are trying compile to see if `R1549aadb` appears in the file; e.g. at line 11.

Comment: @StephenC, the error message look exactly as the snippet above, the line number for these errors always seems to correspond to import statement. I've seen it correspond to JDK and external classes, i.e. import java.util.GregorianCalendar;